# Não consigo declarar variável dentro do id

Tags: php, pdo, variáveis, post, if

```
@$c_id = $_POST['numero'];
@$data_aa = $_POST['data_aa']; // Data esta vazio

if($data_aa == ''){
$var = "oi";
echo "$var";
}
```

Se eu pôr a variável `$var` fora do `if()`, funciona normalmente.

Comment: Como está seu html?

Comment: Amigo acabei de conseguir, mt obrigado pela ajuda e atenção!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazendo `!=` de vazio (*null*)

```
if ($data_aa != null) {
    // funcionou!!!
}
```